# I am unable to install windows .net 4.6.1 using wine 2.0 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine

I am unable to install windows .net 4.6.1 using wine 2.0 in ubuntu 16.04

I am trying to install Family Tree Maker 2017 and this is a prerequisite.

As soon as the installation of .net 461 gets to the dialog box to show installation progress, the installation aborts.

I installed wine 2.0 using the instructions at https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Thank you